# iOS Keychain - What is its internal underlying structure?

Tags: objective-c, keychain

I'm currently reading up on the iOS keychain, but one thing I am unsure is how best to describe or otherwise understand its internal underlying structure?

By which I mean, the query is about the file/data structure which I'm a bit unsure about.

Many thanks

Comment: Probably a sqlite database.

Comment: i think its more of a key, value store. But I haven't found evidence either way

Comment: Closed. Its like a PLIST